# ExtJS ComboBox - Prevent default selection action

Tags: combobox, extjs4

I want to prevent the default action of the combobox setting its value to the selected item in the picker. I just want to see the values in the picker and, when I click on them, nothing to happen. How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean you want it to be a "dummy" field that has no value submitted by the form?

Comment: I want it to behave exactly like a combo box, except when I click an element from the picker, it should not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    ...
    listeners: {
        beforeselect: function() {return false;}
    }
});
```

ExtJS still handles the DOM click internally and figures out the record that you clicked on (and you have a reference to it in beforeselect handler, see the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-beforeselect)), however returning **false** in the *beforeselect* event handler would prevent selecting the record and any further actions.